# Blackberry - send sms timeout

Tags: blackberry

I have simple code to send sms. It works fine. Just little problem. How can I figure out that sms can not be send? Some timeout for Connection or other way? Let's say if there is no network, no sim card or no credit. Thanks
Here is code:

```
 public static void sendSMS(String content, String number) {
        MessageConnection mc = null;
        TextMessage msg;
        try {

            mc = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + number,Connector.WRITE,true);
            msg = (TextMessage) mc.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
            msg.setPayloadText(content);
            mc.send(msg);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
                }
            });

        } finally {
            try {
                if (mc != null) {
                    mc.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void sendSMS(final String no, final String msg) {

    try {

        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                if (RadioInfo.getNetworkType() == RadioInfo.NETWORK_CDMA) {

                    DatagramConnection dc = null;

                    try {

                        dc = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + no);

                        byte[] data = msg.getBytes();

                        Datagram dg = dc.newDatagram(dc.getMaximumLength());

                        dg.setData(data, 0, data.length);

                        dc.send(dg);

                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                                try {

                                    System.out.println("Message Sent Successfully : Datagram");

                                    Dialog.alert("Message Sent Successfully");

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    System.out.println("Exception **1 : " + e.toString());

                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }

                            }

                        });

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Exception 1 : " + e.toString());

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {

                        try {

                            dc.close();

                            dc = null;

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            System.out.println("Exception 2 : " + e.toString());

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                } else {

                    MessageConnection conn = null;

                    try {

                        conn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + no);

                        //generate a new text message

                        TextMessage tmsg = (TextMessage) conn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);

                        //set the message text and the address

                        tmsg.setAddress("sms://" + no);

                        tmsg.setPayloadText(msg);

                        //finally send our message

                        conn.send(tmsg);

                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                                try {

                                    System.out.println("Message Sent Successfully : TextMessage");

                                    Dialog.alert("Message Sent Successfully : TextMessage");

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    System.out.println("Exception **1 : " + e.toString());

                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }

                            }

                        });

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Exception 3 : " + e.toString());

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {

                        try {

                            conn.close();

                            conn = null;

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            System.out.println("Exception 4 : " + e.toString());

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception 5 : " + e.toString());

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```